# Setting command execution result to variable in Makefile

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, makefile, aws-cli

My makefile is setup for bash shell. How can I assign result of a command execution to a variable and print the value in Makefile?

I want to assign the output of an AWS cli command execution to a variable in Makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the make [Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) command to do this.  A simple example:

#### Makefile:

```
TEST := $(shell date)
.PHONY: all
all:
        @echo "We now know the date is ${TEST}!"
```

#### Demo:

```sh
$ make all
We now know the date is Mon 18 Nov 11:53:13 GMT 2019!
```

Comment: Thanks , can’t a variable be defined within a Target? Can’t TEST declaration be moved within all?

Comment: Anything run in a target is run in a sub-shell that is set up by Makel.  Thus these will only set envrionment variables within the shell envrionment that is active for that target *only*, meaning that they will be lost once that shell is closed.  This is quite subtle and shouldn't be mistaken with variables within Make itself!  A possible "workaround" would be to recursively call make within your target (`$(MAKE) <target> TEST="$(shell <command>)"`), but this is quite ugly and can open up a new can of worms with regards to recursive Make issues - depending on your setup.

Comment: Thanks , this helps!